# Nitrous.io console mouse sensitivity

Tags: nitrousio

Is there a way to configure the mouse sensitivity within the console of a nitrous box? I've noticed that it's extremely sensitive on macs with a magic mouse. It becomes frustrating when trying to view test output (or anything) that requires a scroll in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found anyway to do this yet via the web interface. The best I've been able to do is use Nitrous Desktop to ssh into the remote machine and run my tests using my native desktop terminal. You can also use nitrous desktop to sync your files and work on your project locally.